# Javascript- Simple function and object not working

Tags: object

```
var paper=new Object();
paper.color="red";
paper.height= function(a+b){
return a+b;
}
document.write(paper.height(10,11));
```

Why's this not working?
Someone please explain..

Comment: You have a typo `+` instead of `,`: `paper.height= function(a,b){`

Answer (score 1):

Your function definition is incorrect.  "a+b" isn't valid for arguments, you need to comma separate them:

```
paper.height = function(a,b) { return a + b; };
```

Answer (score 0):

function(a+b) should be function(a, b)

```
var paper = {};
paper.color = "red";
paper.height = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
document.write(paper.height(10, 11));
```